# Activity life cycle recreate() method doesn't work properly when changing language

Tags: android, spinner, multilingual

I want to make multi language apps with spinner, i got bugs. When changing the language then my app create so many page, in this case i call MainActivity page. and also progress dialog won't appear when translating language.
how i can to fix it?
here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_page);
    setDefaultToolbar(true);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Translating...");

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_language);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.language, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 1) {
                setLocale("in");
                progressDialog.show();

            }
            else if (pos == 2) {
                setLocale("en");
                progressDialog.show();

            }

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}
public void setLocale(String lang) {

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    this.recreate();
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Did you try this : MainActivity.recreate(); ?

Comment: Not yet..i use this.recreate()

Comment: Try it then make a comment if it works or not

Comment: MainActivity.recreate() cannot be applied

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,After changing Locale this way, restart your activity.

```
    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
               // String lang = getLanguageFromPrefs(context);
                return setLocale(context, defaultLanguage);
            }
    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
              //  saveLanguageToPrefs(language,context);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    return updateResources(context, language);
                }

                return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
            }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
   private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
                Locale locale = new Locale(language);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
                configuration.setLocale(locale);

                return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
            }
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
                Locale locale = new Locale(language);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);

                Resources resources = context.getResources();

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                    configuration.setLocale(locale);
                } else {
                    configuration.locale = locale;
                }

                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                return context;
            }
```

**Updated**

Now do this:

```
Context context=onAttach(MainActivity.this,"YourLanguage") //eg. ar or en,fr...
this.recreate();
```

Comment: @asqa in activity class

Comment: can't find saveLanguageToPrefs

Comment: just comment out that

Answer (score 0):

Try finishing the current activity and starting a new one:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```